# Using Firebase storage with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular5, angularfire5

I'm converting my code to start using AF5 to interact with Firebase Storage but I am also configuring the metadata with `firebase.storage.UploadMetadata`. Can that be changed with AF5 and avoid importing the firebase library?

Answer (score 0):

Still, it hasn’t been publicly released.So you might need to install it as `angularfire2@next`.

*Can that be changed with AF5 and avoid importing the firebase library?*

Yes, You don't need to import entire firebase library.You just need to import `AngularFireStorageModule`.

```
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from 'angularfire2/storage';
```

Here you can [**read more about it**](https://javebratt.com/angularfire2-storage-api/).